# How to convert the multi fasta file header into single fasta header?

Tags: python, unix, fasta

I have a multifasta file as shown below

```
>t_xth_1
MNGTGHA
>t_xth_1
MNGTGHA
>ocean
MNGTGHA
>ocean
MNGTGHA
>sea
MNGTGHA
```

I need to convert the above fasta file to below shown file format (expected output),

```
>t_xth_1
MNGTGHA
MNGTGHA
>ocean
MNGTGHA
MNGTGHA
>sea
MNGTGHA
```

Please help me to do the same.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `awk` is an option

```
$ awk '/^>/ {if ($0 == prev) next; prev = $0} 1' file
>t_xth_1
MNGTGHA
MNGTGHA
>ocean
MNGTGHA
MNGTGHA
>sea
MNGTGHA
```

On records that match the regexp `^>`: go to the next record if the current record is the same as the `prev` variable, otherwise update `prev`. The trailing `1` will `print` the current record.